# How to set values for a set of a bean object from jsp using Spring MVC 3.0

Tags: spring-mvc

Here is my bean

```
package com.sasken.sewa.dto;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Set;

public class SewaGroup implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int group_id;
private String group_name;
private SewaMember group_leader_1;
private SewaMember group_leader_2;
private Village village;
private Double openingbalance_insurance;
private Double openingbalance_employment;
private Double openingbalance_saving;
private Double current_balance;
private Double insurance_fund;
    private Double employment_fund;
    private Double saving;
private boolean active_status;
private Timestamp golive_date;
private Timestamp deleted_on;
private String bankAccountNumber;
private String bankName;
//private Set<SewaMember> sewamembers;
    private Set<SewaGroupMembers> sewagroupmembers;

    private Set<GroupInstallment> groupInstallment;

private Set<SewaOperator> sewaoperators;

public int getGroup_id() {
    return group_id;
}
public void setGroup_id(int group_id) {
    this.group_id = group_id;
}
public String getGroup_name() {
    return group_name;
}
public void setGroup_name(String group_name) {
    this.group_name = group_name;
}
public SewaMember getGroup_leader_1() {
    return group_leader_1;
}
public void setGroup_leader_1(SewaMember group_leader_1) {
    this.group_leader_1 = group_leader_1;
}
public SewaMember getGroup_leader_2() {
    return group_leader_2;
}
public void setGroup_leader_2(SewaMember group_leader_2) {
    this.group_leader_2 = group_leader_2;
}
public Village getVillage() {
    return village;
}
public void setVillage(Village village) {
    this.village = village;
}



public Double getOpeningbalance_insurance() {
    return openingbalance_insurance;
}
public void setOpeningbalance_insurance(Double openingbalance_insurance) {
    this.openingbalance_insurance = openingbalance_insurance;
}
public Double getOpeningbalance_employment() {
    return openingbalance_employment;
}
public void setOpeningbalance_employment(Double openingbalance_employment) {
    this.openingbalance_employment = openingbalance_employment;
}
public Double getOpeningbalance_saving() {
    return openingbalance_saving;
}
public void setOpeningbalance_saving(Double openingbalance_saving) {
    this.openingbalance_saving = openingbalance_saving;
}
public String getBankAccountNumber() {
    return bankAccountNumber;
}
public void setBankAccountNumber(String bankAccountNumber) {
    this.bankAccountNumber = bankAccountNumber;
}
public String getBankName() {
    return bankName;
}
public void setBankName(String bankName) {
    this.bankName = bankName;
}
public Double getCurrent_balance() {
    return current_balance;
}
public void setCurrent_balance(Double current_balance) {
    this.current_balance = current_balance;
}
public boolean isActive_status() {
    return active_status;
}
public void setActive_status(boolean active_status) {
    this.active_status = active_status;
}
public Timestamp getGolive_date() {
    return golive_date;
}
public void setGolive_date(Timestamp golive_date) {
    this.golive_date = golive_date;
}
public Timestamp getDeleted_on() {
    return deleted_on;
}
public void setDeleted_on(Timestamp deleted_on) {
    this.deleted_on = deleted_on;
}
public Set<SewaOperator> getSewaoperators() {
    return sewaoperators;
}
public void setSewaoperators(Set<SewaOperator> sewaoperators) {
    this.sewaoperators = sewaoperators;
}
public Set<SewaGroupMembers> getSewagroupmembers() {
    return sewagroupmembers;
}
public void setSewagroupmembers(Set<SewaGroupMembers> sewagroupmembers) {
    this.sewagroupmembers = sewagroupmembers;
}
public Set<GroupInstallment> getGroupInstallment() {
    return groupInstallment;
}
public void setGroupInstallment(Set<GroupInstallment> groupInstallment) {
    this.groupInstallment = groupInstallment;
}
/*public String getGroupAccountNumber() {
    return bankAccountNumber;
}
public void setGroupAccountNumber(String bankAccountNumber) {
    this.bankAccountNumber = bankAccountNumber;
}*/
public Double getInsurance_fund() {
    return insurance_fund;
}
public void setInsurance_fund(Double insurance_fund) {
    this.insurance_fund = insurance_fund;
}
public Double getEmployment_fund() {
    return employment_fund;
}
public void setEmployment_fund(Double employment_fund) {
    this.employment_fund = employment_fund;
}
public Double getSaving() {
    return saving;
}
public void setSaving(Double saving) {
    this.saving = saving;
}



}
```

Jsp page

```
<form:form method="post" action="/SEWATemp/add_new_sewa_group"
modelAttribute="sewaGroup">

<fieldset>
    <legend>SimpleAjaxDemo:</legend>
    <table>

        <tr>
            <td>SEWA group_name</td>
            <td><form:input path="group_name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SEWA group_leader_1</td>
            <td><form:input path="group_leader_1.member_name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>group_leader_2</td>
            <td><form:input path="group_leader_2.member_name" /></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bank Name</td>
            <td><form:input path="bankName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>groupAccountNumber</td>
            <td><form:input path="bankAccountNumber" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>groupInstallment</td>

            <c:forEach var="group"         items="${sewaGroup.groupInstallment}"
                varStatus="vs">

                <td><form:input path="group.installment_amount" /></td>
            </c:forEach>

        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>operatorName</td>
            <td><form:select path="sewaoperators" id="operatorName">
                    <form:option value="">select SKK</form:option>
                    <c:forEach var="operator" items="${operatorList}">
                        <form:option value="${operator.operator_id}">${operator.operator_member.member_name}</form:option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </form:select></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</fieldset>
```

My issue is how to set the value for sewaoperators from jsp.
The error i am getting is Type mismatch cannot convert from java.lang.String[] to java.util.set

Please reply to this question .

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Array of String, sewaoperators[] as transient object like this:

```
@Transient
public String[](or List<String>) getSewaoperators() {
        return sewaoperators;
}
```

on receiving the model attribute,  you convert the array(list) to your own entity class.
If not, the spring doesn't know how to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a selected value from operatorList to a Set type (in form:select) in this way. You need to use another field in your SewaGroup as say:

```
    private String selectedOperator;
    //setters and getters of selectedOperator
```

Make changes to jsp as:

```
    <form:select path="selectedOperator" id="operatorName">
        ...
    </form:select>
```

When you submit this, in your controller or whatever handler you have to process this, you have to compare selectedOperator value with operatorList, get the operator and assign the remaining fields from this operator(because you have not specified the datatype of this operator in question) to SewaOperator and then add this SewaOperator to set.